# Where is the error in this proof? Sigma algebras.

Tags: measure-theory

> **Claim:** Suppose $\mathfrak{F}$ is a algebra, then $\mathfrak{F}$ is a
>   sigma algebra.

Since $\mathfrak{F}$ is an algebra we only need to prove that it is closed under countable unions to conclude it is also a sigma algebra.

Let $A_1,A_2,... \in \mathfrak{F}$ we aim to show $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i \in \mathfrak{F}$ we can use induction to proceed.

Clearly $A_1 \cup A_2 \in \mathfrak{F}$ since $\mathfrak{F}$ is an algebra.

Then suppose it holds for $A_1 \cup...\cup A_n$ but then it will hold for $A_1 \cup...\cup A_n \cup A_{n+1}$ since $A_1 \cup...\cup A_n \in \mathfrak{F}$ and $\mathfrak{F}$ is an algebra.

If at each extra union it is still in $\mathfrak{F}$ then why can't we say the infinite union would also belong to $\mathfrak{F}$?

I guess I am lacking the proper rigour to deal with countable unions but to my mind this should work could anyone explain why it doesn't?

Comment: The infinite union is not simply the "limit" of finite unions. Think of this equivalence of countable additivity: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(\Sigma_{i=1}^n X_i)=\mu(\Sigma_{i=1}^\infty X_i)$. This does not hold for a finite-additive $\mu$ in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So take a simple example.  The set $X = \mathbb N$, and $\mathcal F$ the collection of subsets that are either finite or have finite complement $\mathbb N$.  This $\mathcal F$ is an algebra.

But not a $\sigma$-algebra.  Suppose we claim the set $E$ of even numbers belongs to $\mathcal F$.  Following your proof, we can show that $\{0,2,4,\dots,2k\} \in \mathcal F$ for every $k$.  But of course the "infinite union" $E = \{0,2,4,6,\dots\}$ does not belong to $\mathcal F$ ... it is neither finite nor is its complement finite.

Comment: Nice example, guess relying on "intuition" when dealing with infinity is not a good idea. Thank you.